# CDN htaccess allow access to multiple domains

Tags: api, .htaccess, cdn

we need to create a cdn with a series of icons, we would like to limit access (via htaccess or something?). So deny it to all but only allow it to some domains. How can we do?

We tried to use this syntax

```
# Order Allow, Deny
Deny from All
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

and this syntax but it doesnt work very well:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^https?://[^/]*(firstdomain|seconddomain)" ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ORIGIN}e env=ORIGIN
```

Comment: _"We need to allow websites"_ - the requests for those images are not made by the websites - but by the client browsers.

Comment: We need to block everyone try to get the information but allow only websites

Comment: You can not do that using Allow/Deny. It is not any website that makes the request to your server - it is the user's browser. You will need to use a solution that checks the HTTP referrer.

Comment: So how we can do this?

Comment: We need every user that go on a specific domains see this icons and if someone try to link our cdn block

Comment: HTTP referrer is one keyword for your to research, "hotlink protection" is another.

Comment: I resolved using this: SetEnvIf Origin "^https?://[^/]*(domain1|domain2)" ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ORIGIN}e env=ORIGIN

Comment: That should only have an effect, if the images get embedded with the crossorigin attribute set. If not, then the browser has no reason to care about this response header to begin with. (And even if it is set, I don't know how browsers react if the request is _not_ in fact cross-origin; they might still simply ignore it then.)

Comment: we linked a css not a folder of image